# How to change the label inside the input by jQuery from no to yes after click

Tags: jquery

How to change the label form no to yes after click the yes?

```css
        .sb2
        {
            width: 20%;
            font-size: 15px;
            padding: 9px 0px 0px 0px;
            -webkit-appearance: none;
            box-shadow: none;
        }
        .ye {
            background: #fff;
            position: relative;
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            align-content: flex-end;
            justify-content: space-between;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
        }
        .ye input {
            outline: none;
            cursor: pointer;
            justify-content: flex-end;
            align-items: center;
            align-content: flex-end;
            border-radius: 1px;
            height: 25px;
            appearance: none;
            color: #3498db;
            border: 1px solid black;
            font-family: inherit;
            padding: 3px 0px 0px 0px;
        }
        .ye input:checked {
            background-color: #4f94d4;
            color: #fff;
        }
        .ye input:before {
            content: attr(label);
            display: inline-block;
            text-align: center;
            width: 100%;
        }
        .private{
            width: 80%;
            font-size: 13px;
            padding: 2px 0px 0px 0px;
            text-align:left;
            height:25px;
            background:#5a605d;
            color:#f5f5f5;
            font-weight:500;
            border:1px solid black;
        }
```

How to change the label form no to yes after click the yes

```
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <div class="ye">
        <span class="private">one</span> 
        <input name="t_1" type="checkbox" class="sb2" label="no">
        <span class="private">two</span>
        <input name="t_2" type="checkbox" class="sb2" label="no">
        <span class="private">three</span>
        <input name="t_3" type="checkbox" class="sb2" label="no">
        </div>
```

How to change the label form no to yes after click the yes

Comment: do it - `$("input.sb2").on("change", function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $(this).attr("label", "yes");
  } else {
    $(this).attr("label", "no");
  }
});`

Comment: thanks so much I will become good at share

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
$('.ye input.sb2').click(function() {
  $(this).attr("label",function() {
    return $(this).attr("label") == "no" ? "yes" : "no"
  })
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$('.ye input.sb2').click(function() {
  $(this).attr("label",function() {
    return $(this).attr("label") == "no" ? "yes" : "no"
  })
});
```

```css
.sb2 {
  width: 20%;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 9px 0px 0px 0px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.ye {
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: flex-end;
  justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.ye input {
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: flex-end;
  border-radius: 1px;
  height: 25px;
  appearance: none;
  color: #3498db;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-family: inherit;
  padding: 3px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.ye input:checked {
  background-color: #4f94d4;
  color: #fff;
}

.ye input:before {
  content: attr(label);
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.private {
  width: 80%;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 2px 0px 0px 0px;
  text-align: left;
  height: 25px;
  background: #5a605d;
  color: #f5f5f5;
  font-weight: 500;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
how to change the label form no to yes after click the yes
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ye">
  <span class="private">one</span>
  <input name="t_1" type="checkbox" class="sb2" label="no">
  <span class="private">two</span>
  <input name="t_2" type="checkbox" class="sb2" label="no">
  <span class="private">three</span>
  <input name="t_3" type="checkbox" class="sb2" label="no">
</div>
```